# After reaching the bottom of page, how to make user scroll to another specific page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Is there any way which I can make the page be like:
After the user scroll to the bottom of page, if they scroll again, and it will auto go to other specific page.

For example, the user scroll until to the bottom/ending of the page A, when he scroll again at that bottom, it will lead him to page C. What is this feature call? And jQuery can make it or not?

I don't have any HTML code or code using, because I am asking whether is there a jQuery function like this or not. How can I post the code of whole html page?

Comment: Please post your html code:

Comment: you mean infinite scroll like facebook timeline?

Comment: don't have html code. it's not infinite scroll, but something like scroll to next page/other page

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) window.location = "page2.html";
});
```

**JS Desktop**:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) == document.body.offsetHeight) window.location = "page2.html";
};
```

**JS mobile**:

```
document.body.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) == document.body.offsetHeight) window.location = "page2.html";
};
```

I did not test it since I am on mobile. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and use redirect or another function to change the page.

This detects if you are at the bottom of page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```